# take() on union of Observable expects what?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Well this one had me surprised :

```
import {Observable, take} from 'rxjs';

declare const obs$: Observable<null> | Observable<string>;    
obs$.pipe(take())
```

throws this magnificent :

```
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.(2554)
```

I know the root cause is that the method on a union type takes the intersection of parameter types. But well, this one is ... curious.

The obvious fix is using `Observable<string | null>` but I'm looking for the reason of this error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwPICMDOBTKA3AhigGwwBo4ZcBrDAXzgDMoIQ4ByKADwCs0WBuAKH4ATDAGMCuKBjiiIAOzTwI6ACQAuOKkw58RADxyArgQIA%20OAB9N6LHkIY9iqMDkBzUwP7K0KgHRhgMAwACnIqYIBKCKA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had the base problem (intersection of parameters on a method of a union) but didn't apply it to the right methods.

`pipe()` on a union of incompatible observable takes no parameters, hence the 1st error.

`take()` always takes a parameter, hence the 2nd error.

Comment: What do you mean by incompatible observables?

Comment: `string` & `null` for example have no intersection !

Comment: According to this [answer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3388#issuecomment-371672512) on Github the problem is with the overload signatures of pipe, which do not match (except the one with no parameters) types like `Observable<X> | Observable<Y>` in general independent of the compatibility of X and Y. At least that is what I read from that answer.